# How to add layouts to another view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, view

I tried to create a list of buttons that going to hold a image and below of that button there will be a text. That's why i created `friend_button.xml` to create a button and text as a component so i can multiply this component and change features in each multiplication. But unfortunately, when it tries to add the view to the layout (or reverse like add the layout to the view) it gives me error that says rootView has already a parent. I tried to find the parent (ny using that code "`rootView.getParent().getClass().getName().toString()`") and it said "`android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`" is the parent. I don't know whether CoordinatorLayout is its parent or not, i tried to remove my rootView from that parent so i can add it to my layout, but i couldn't do it. My question is that, is this the correct way to do what i am doing, if it is, what is the problem that i am facing?

```
public class FriendsList extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
  SharedPreferences settings;
  String token;
  String fname,lname;
  ArrayList<JsonObject> friendsJsonObjects = new ArrayList<JsonObject>();
  ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
  RelativeLayout main;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int i;

    settings = getSharedPreferences("vacaYouSettings", 0);
    token = settings.getString("access_key", "");
    /*getAllFriends() gets friends adds the name of the friends to friends arraylist*/
    getAllFriends();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends_list);
    main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    ImageButton[] friendImage = new ImageButton[friends.size()];
    TextView[] friendName = new TextView[friends.size()];

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_button, main);

    Log.d("viev",rootView.getParent().getClass().getName().toString());

        for (i = 0; i < friends.size(); i++) {


            friendImage[i] = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            friendName[i] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            friendName[i].setId(i);
            friendImage[i].setId(i);
            friendName[i].setText(friends.get(i));
            friendName[i].setText("deneme");
            main.addView(rootView);
        }


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);'
```

I couldn't copy my xml codes. I just took screenshots so you can see the mainLayout (actual name is content_friends_list.xml) and friend_button.xml

[friend_button.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWEMD.png)

[mainLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6alqS.png)

Comment: Post the stacktrace please

Comment: What do you mean by stacktrace? The values of variables in debugging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method signature is

```
inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

When inflating the view, set `attachToRoot` to **false**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_button, main, false);
```

That way, the rootView will not have automatically a parent when instantiated, and you'll be able to add that later.

#### Edit

You can also try to do everything programatically.

So, you'd have something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < friends.size(); i++) {

    LinearLayout currentLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    ImageButton currentImageButton = new ImageButton(context);
    TextView currentTextView = new TextView(context);
    currentTextView.setText("....");
        
    currentLayout.addView(currentImageButton)
    currentLayout.addView(currentTextView);
       
    main.addView(currentLayout);
}
```

And erase these lines:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_button, main);
```

Comment: I did what you say and the error is still same "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." the error occurs in "main.add(rootView);"

Comment: What if you remove this line? `main.addView(rootView);`

Comment: When i remove that line, everything is good, it is running but without any button and also i add [the photo of how it looks like without that line](http://i.hizliresim.com/dZrYLr.png)

Comment: i should i write instead of context? is it variable ?

Comment: exactly same error on "main.addView(linearLayout);" line.

Comment: @OzanPolatbilek So do everything programatically as I posted. It works fine here.

Comment: The code is like [this](http://i.hizliresim.com/MgQOja.png) right now. There may be some changes about size of for loop or some little changes but generally the main part is like what you want it to be.

Comment: @OzanPolatbilek Actually its different. You will not use the inflater to inflate a new View, you'll do everything dinamically. Take a look at the edit

Comment: yes it works, It adds a button and a textview, but i want to add my button and my textview as a whole. In the first answer, as a comment, i explained what i wanted. Yes this works but it just adds a normal button and normal text view without my design.

Comment: @OzanPolatbilek Yes, my friend, the code I posted is just a plain button and a plain TextView. You'd have to customize it the way you want. i.e. add code so that the result matches your `.xml` file. For example, you'd have to set the imagebutton background by doing `currentImageButton.setBackground(R.drawable.oval_background);`, set the margins, set the `TextView` height etc etc etc. Basically, transform your `xml` into `java`.

Comment: Oh okay then that explains how to do, but i want to ask one more thing, is it possible to add my layout to the main layout, like i tried to do before. Button and textview as a component, all together. Adding layout from another xml to other xml, is it possible ? By the way, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @OzanPolatbilek Yeah I know that is not what you were looking for, but that's a workaround. Answering to your question: yes, it is possible. I'm not home right now, without Android Studio. But I'll try to do it the way you're trying to do and post here the results as soon as possible.